# Jenkins giving error while giving repository URL to source code management

Tags: java, git, github, jenkins

I'm configuring the GitHub project in Jenkins while entering all the details got struck in Source Code Management -> Git -> Repositories -> Gave the Repository URL - https://github.com/xxx/gradle-java-sample-project.git

showed this message -

Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://github.com/xxx/gradle-java-sample-project.git HEAD" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

I checked in configure System, Git and GitHub plugins were installed.
Not sure what I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have not installed the command line tools. Run this code in Terminal on your Mac.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I gave the repo URL as - https://github.com/xxx/gradle-java-sample-project.git then it showed me that message with that command.

Comment: When are you getting this error? It looks like you have some trouble with the command line tools.

Comment: Glad It was helpful Accept the answer and up vote it :)